# Does node's exec call block meteor application?

Tags: node.js, meteor, phantomjs, node-fibers

I am building a meteor application that creates pdf files from a web page using phantomjs.

PhantomJS is called with node's `child_process.exec` function within a fiber using `Meteor._wrapAsync`. When I am using any url like google.com, it is working fine and the pdf is created.

The problem is, I want to capture a site served by the same meteor application at /invoicePDF. But during the execution of phantomjs the site apparently does not load, thus, it cannot load inside phantomjs, which makes finishing the call to phantomjs impossible.

Comment: Does it load when you call the phantomjs with your script directly? If not, please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#webpage-onConsoleMessage) and [`onError`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#onerror) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: When phantomjs is called directly, it works. `onConsoleMessage` and `onError` do not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seemed to be to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` instead of `Meteor._wrapAsync`. Unfortunately, I have know idea why.

Comment: You can accept the answer now. Maybe someone will write an answer detailing why this happens.